# Audio freezes for 8 seconds every minute or so when using microphone, every device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audacity, google-hangouts

For the past several months, I have had a problem with any time I am using the microphone -- VOIP and video conferencing, plain audio recording.   It works fine for a minute or so, then audio cuts out in both directions for about 5 seconds, then resumes.   This also happens when I just record audio in audacity, and it reports large runs of "lost 800 samples" from the capture.   I recently updated to 18.04.4 hoping the latest builds might fix it, but it's driving me nuts in our lockdown world.

It happens with all audio input devices -- built in analog, various USB microphones.  It happens with all tools -- audacity, hangouts, skype, zoom, though I sense it happens less with skype.   Some buffer seems to be overflowing or something else.

Looking for advice on how to fix this, or failing that, to just remove and restore my audio system to "factory" to see if that gets rid of the problem.  I have pulseaudio and alsa in what I think is fairly number, though run on cinnamon rather than KDE or gnome desktops.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing the [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) kernel:

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`

However, the fact that your problem seems to affect a variety of different hardware might mean there is no benefit from the more modern drivers.

Comment: Looks like a worthwhile thing to do but seems unlikely to make the difference here.  I mean we're talking about just buffering audio, on a system that handled audio just fine for many years through versions of Ubuntu going back probably to 12.04 but just got the problem late last year for unknown reasons.